# Most important things you should do after your VPS server has been "built"?

Tags: linux, debian, debian-lenny

I'm trying to write a [guide](http://medero.org/debian/) with some essentials that one should do after his/her server has finished "building", important things like setting up a secondary user that's non-root, locales, perhaps even disabling a password login and using keys instead. If you do decide to participate mind providing code examples in addition to a small description?

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` to update package lists and install the latest security updates for packages, and also installing `aptitude` and relying on it since it handles dependencies better.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get install locales` if you don't already have it installed. type `locale` and if you see any warnings at the top, do `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, select your locale ( mine is en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 ), generate and that should be taken care of, to avoid any locale issues when installing / upgrading packages.

Answer (score 1):

1) Enable spoofing protect and syncookies:

```
spoofprotect=yes
syncookies=yes
```

2) For server will be enough 3 consoles. Edit /etc/inittab:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
2:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2
3:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty3
#4:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty4
#5:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty5
#6:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty6
```

3) [Secure OpenSSH](http://www.sysadmin.md/secure-existing-openssh-installation.html)

4) Install utils:

```
aptitude install screen htop
```

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get install aptitude` to grab the front end apt wrapper which handles dependencies far better. After doing so ( or if you already have it ), install some "essential" packages with `aptitude install ~pstandard` which grabs packages such as `perl` and `dnsutils`.